# Is there an option that can display all of my variables in one graph using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

My data is in long format and looks like this

```
  name     NPV Cost_Household Cost_Plant
  <chr>  <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>
1 11kWp 15746.          1932.     13865.
2 9kWp  13640.          2374.     11344.
3 5kWp   7537.          3134.      6302.
4 3kWp   4649.          3684.      3781.
```

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
Results_Case2_Annuity %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = values, y = name, fill = name)) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: You don't need the image - the text-format example you've already given is sufficient, and is preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You usually have to "melt" ("pivot", "gather") your data to long format first. `dplyr::pivot_longer()` or `reshape2::melt()` are probably the easiest ways to do this.

Creating an example data set to work with from the information given:

```r
dd <- read.table(header= TRUE, text = "
name     NPV Cost_Household Cost_Plant
11kWp 15746.          1932.     13865.
9kWp  13640.          2374.     11344.
5kWp   7537.          3134.      6302.
3kWp   4649.          3684.      3781.
")
```

I'm guessing this is what you want:

```r
dd_long <- dd  |> pivot_longer(-name, names_to = "var") |>
    ## I would say you also want your names in numeric order?
    mutate(across(name, ~factor(., levels = gtools::mixedsort(unique(.)))))
```

- The first line converts to long format. `-name` means that you *don't* want to include `name` in the set of variables that are "melted". `names_to="var"` specifies what to call the identifier column that will be created from the column names (the default is "name", which clashes with the existing "name" column ...)
- The `mutate(across(...))` stuff is optional, but specifies that the ordering of your names should be {3kWp, 5kWp, 9kWp, 11kWp} — the default alphabetical order puts "11kWp" first. (You need to have the `gtools` package installed to use this: `mixedsort()` is a utility function that's helpful for sorting labels that combine numeric and alphabetical components.)

```r
ggplot(dd_long) +
  aes(x = name, y = value, fill = var) + 
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben 
Thanks for your quick answer.
But I think my knowledge of R is a little too poor to understand your answer. I would also like to be able to generate the plot that you have created. The values are already contained in a dataset that is called Results_Case2_Annuity and also only consists of this data. 

Can you please help me again and tell me how I have to convert the ggplot?
Thank you very much

Comment: I added a picture of my data in my question.

Comment: I called the data set `dd` in my example instead of `Results_Case2_Annuity`. If you substitute `Results_Case2_Annuity` for `dd` in my code and run it  you should get a plot ...

Comment: Sorry, the picture is from case 1 and the other from case 2, but they are the same in structure.

Comment: then I get this error:

Error in `mutate()`:
ℹ In argument: `across(name, ~factor(., levels = gtools::mixedsort(unique(.))))`.
Caused by error in `across()`:
! Can't compute column `name`.
Caused by error in `loadNamespace()`:
! there is no package called ‘gtools’
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: you need to install the `gtools` package.